# Javascript function not defined when call from browser console

Tags: javascript, undefined

```
var ready = function ready(callback) {
      if (document.readyState != "loading") callback();else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    };
    ready(function () {
      "use strict"; 
      var callBstApi = function callBstApi(params) {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/myApi", {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(params)
        }).then(function (data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log('test is cancelled!');
        });
      };
    });
```

When I call callBstApi(myParams) onload it works but if I call that function from my browser console it shows below error
[image: Error!!!]

I have to write script in vanilla js.

Comment: That is because `callBstApi` is enclosed in the `ready` function and it is not available to the global scope. If you want to expose it, instead of doing `var callBstApi` you can do `window.callBstApi = ...`. You can then access the function `callBstApi` in the window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further extend on my comment: the reason why `callBstApi` is not available in your console is because it is not present in the global scope. The function is defined inside your `ready` function and is therefore inaccessible. To circumvent this, you will want to expose the method to the global window scope. This can be done by doing so:

```
window.callBstApi = ...
```

You can now access `callBstApi` in the global scope (with or without the `window.` prefix, that is completely optional) and invoke it as such:

```
callBstApi(myParams);

// If you want to be pedantic, you can do:
window.callBstApi(myParams);
```

p/s: The only risk is that you'll overwrite whatever that's there, if that key is already found in the `window` object.